# Selenium test no longer creating a temporary Chrome profile using Chrome Driver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using C# and Visual Studio. I'm using the current version of the Selenium.Support and Selenium.WebDriver packages.

Previously when I ran a Selenium test in Chrome it would open with a temporary profile by default. This would ensure there was a fresh session and none of the cookies from any other profile would potentially pollute the test results.

Since updating Chrome to version 115 (I am not positive this is the cause. It just correlates.) I am no longer seeing this behavior. When I run a test now it opens a new blank tab in an existing window and nothing else happens. I get the below error presumably because Selenium can't attach to the existing session.

```
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I have tried many combinations of Chrome Options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
                options.AddArgument("disable-dev-shm-usage");
                options.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
                options.AddArgument("remote-debugging-port=9222");
                //options.AddArgument("incognito");
                options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
                options.AddArgument("enable-automation");
                options.AddArgument("test-type");
                options.AddArgument("remote-allow-origins=*");
                options.AddArgument("disable-notifications");
                options.AddArgument("dns-prefetch-disable");
                options.AddArgument("disable-features=NetworkService");
                //options.AddUserProfilePreference("signin.allowed_on_next_startup", false);
                //options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\\profile");
                //options.AddArgument("profile-directory=<Guest>");
                //options.AddUserProfilePreference("detach", true);
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("autofill.profile_enabled", false);
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

                IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The same behavior is present when using the incognito switch. I have added and removed the debug port and tried 0. No luck. I have pointed it at a new profile using the user-data-dir and profile-directory options. It either didn't start or it did start and didn't work.

The only way I can get a test to run is if I close all Chrome windows and run the test. This allows the test to create a new session and it is able to perform the test. This is not perfect thought because it uses the cache and cookies and stuff that are present in the current profile.

To remedy this I have tried to completely uninstall Chrome and remove all files and completely reinstall and that didn't help. I want to force the test to create a new Temporary Profile like it did before whatever change happened here. I have read everything that I can find on this site and a bunch of others and I can't find anything that actually answers this. I have thought about downgrading but Google doesn't leave old Chrome MSIs out there and I don't want to download a second hand one on my work computer and cause a security problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I added

```
options.AddArgument("guest");
```

and it does open the session as a guest but it still doesn't actually execute the test. It is just an empty tab.

Comment: remove all the options and give it a go... (new ChromeDriver()) if the test works, then go about adding the ones you actually need one at a time.  "remote-debugging-port=9222" is probably the cause here... that'll try and attach to an existing debug session.

Comment: @pcalkins Thank you for your comment. I tried it with a brand new driver without any options being passed in and see the same behavior.

Comment: Do you see Chrome launch? You had mentioned it used an existing window... but what happens when none exists?

Comment: @pcalkins if there are no windows open at all it opens a window and, presumably, because it actually creates the session everything works. If any windows are open it opens a new tab in the an existing window and the test doesn't move past opening the window.